# Expected payoff of the stock price using Montecarlo Simulation

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

Assume that stock currently sells for $80 and follow a geometric Brownian motion and there is an option to purchase the stock price for $40 in 6 months. Then, you can exercise (buy) the option if the price of the stock is greater than $40; but if the stock sells for less than $40, you would not exercise the option and your payoff is nil. So I need to find the expected payoff E(max(P-K,0)).

```
#Simulation of Geometric Brownian Motion
simGBM<- function(P0, mu, sigma, T, nt, ntray){
  dt<-T/nt
  muT<- (mu-sigma^2/2)*dt
  sigmaT<- sqrt(dt)*sigma
  Matrix_norm<- matrix(rnorm(nt*ntray, muT, sigmaT), nrow = ntray)
  Increments_log<- cbind(log(P0), Matrix_norm)
  Tray_log<- t(apply(Increments_log,1,cumsum))
  return(exp(Tray_log))
}

P0<- 80 # Initial price of the stock
K<- 40 # Strike or exercise price
mu<- 0.1 # Drift
sigma<- 0.5 # Volatility
T<- 180/365 # Time measure in years
nt<- 1000 # Number of time steps
ntray<- 1100 # Number of replications or sample paths

paths<- simGBM(P0, mu, sigma, T, nt, ntray)

x<- as.data.frame(paths)
lastrow.x<- (slice(x, (nt+1))) - 40
exp.value<- apply(lastrow.x, 2, function(x) ({ifelse(x<0,0,x)}))

mean(exp.value)
```

Every time I run the code above it generates random numbers totally different for the stock price (i.e from $10 to $70). How I could obtain the expected value of the gain about $40 without large variations?

Comment: Does changing line 12 to `lastrow.x<- x[nrow(x),] - K` give you what you want? At least, might it be that you're confusing rows and columns?

Comment: Or proceed directly from `paths`, without the `as.data.frame` step. `lastrow.paths <- paths[nrow(paths), ] - K; mean(ifelse(lastrow.paths < 0, 0, lastrow.paths))`?

Comment: Thanks so much!! I tried both alternatives but I don't know why the expected value is still very variant @jay.sf

Comment: I also increase number of replications and time steps from 2000 to 5000 to print out a price accuracy

Comment: Might this help: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50030/simulation-of-geometric-brownian-motion-in-r

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You really helped me!! @jay.sf

Comment: I'm glad to hear that @AndreaGarcia